# Linear regression performs better than single-hidden-layer NN?

Tags: regression, neural-networks, dataset

I remember hearing from a professor that there exists a type of dataset for which Linear Regression outperforms single-hidden-layer neural nets. However, I cannot remember what type of dataset he described but I know that it is indeed possible.

To my mind, since single-hidden-layer neural nets can arbitrarily reproduce any function, I can't come up with a dataset that would allow linear regression to outperform NN. So...

**On what kind of dataset can linear regression perform better than single-hidden-layer NN?**

Comment: If the underlying model truly is linear, then you can't do any better than that

Comment: I agree but in this case they will be equivalent, the linear regression will not outperform the NN?

Comment: If they're equivalent then by definition linear regression can't outperform a neural network since then it's just a special case.  But if we require that a non-linear function has to be applied, then this can never be an improvement over the linear model

Comment: @dsaxton hence my question

Comment: It really boils down to the difference between Backpropagation and OLS

Comment: Please,, expand on this?